# How to send a mutation on testing in Laravel using (Lighthouse package)

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

on this [post](https://medium.com/@olivernybroe/testing-graphql-with-laravel-4d6201b40f68) the author made an example helper like this 
and the package being used is the [Lighthouse](https://lighthouse-php.netlify.com)

```
public function graphql(string $query)
{
    return $this->post('/graphql', [
      'query' => $query
    ]);
}
```

and so can be used it like this:

```
$response = $this->graphql("{articles(first: 10) { edges { node { title } } } }");
```

but can I implement that on mutation? if example I have a mutation:

```
type Mutation {
   sampleMutation(
      id: ID!
   )
}
```

I'm not sure how to do that on a mutation.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to test mutations.

In the newest version of Lighthouse you now have a trait you can add to your test class called `MakesGraphQLRequests`.
Taken from their [docs](https://lighthouse-php.com/master/testing/phpunit.html#running-queries) is the following example on how to create a test for a mutation.

```
public function testCreatePost(): void
{
    /** @var \Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestResponse $response */
    $response = $this->postGraphQL([
        'query' => '
            mutation CreatePost($title: String!) {
                createPost(title: $title) {
                    id
                }
            }
        ',
        'variables' => [
            'title' => 'Automatic testing proven to reduce stress levels in developers'
        ],
    ]);
}
```

The response object you get will contain the json result like from your mutation. So here you can just make any json assertions as you normally would with Laravel. 
In their documentation there is [some examples](https://lighthouse-php.com/master/testing/phpunit.html#assertions) on how validation on the json could look like.

Disclaimer: I am the writer of the refered article.